# VB 6.0 Encoding

Tags: vb.net, encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a requirement to read/write binary encrypted file from two applications, one application is VB 6.0 and other is VB.NET.

What is the encoding scheme of VB 6.0 , I am using "ISO-8859-1" , it's very near to accurate but still it gives some error in displaying data in VB.NET app.

What is the different between Chr and Chrw .. why  "ISO-8859-1" scheme is using  Chrw is some places. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure out the issue. The encryption mechanism in VB.NET app was using default Encoding and 
generating characters which were not present in "ISO-8859-1". So the writin to 
file fails.Once I corrected the encryption class to use correct encoding, the problem resolved.

Comment: Note that 'default' encoding on most US / western EU PCs is `Windows-1251`, which is _almost_ identical to `ISO-8859-1`, but not entirely.